# Firefox insert HTML image turns to "undefined" in Hotmail

Tags: firefox, hotmail

On writing email body, when I open HTML editor in Hotmail, put image code for ex:

```
<img src="http://example.org/blabla.jpg" \>
```

and change to rich editor to see the image, it always says `undefined` instead of showing the picture. I have no extensions installed. I tried it on Chrome and it works well. Whats wrong with it, is it only me or Firefox problem?

[image]

Comment: So this is an image linking problem of Hotmail's Rich Text (WYSIWYG) Editor in Firefox? You're sure, that the image exists and that it's displayed in Chrome?

Comment: Yes, I am sure, I posted on mozilla forums and its confirmed. It doesnt matter, write anything, "blabla" and when change it to wysiwyg it becames "undefined". The problem is only in firefox btw.

Comment: Well, Hotmail is a Microsoft product and they haven't necessarily cared about making their websites working seamless in other browsers besides Internet Explorer (no links given here to underline my argumentation ;) ) even with those user numbers rising. However, there is a Mozilla Feedback channel for broken websites in Firefox: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/websites-look-wrong-or-appear-differently#w_report-the-website